# Foreignkey of Django User model to another model

Tags: python, django

I know how to define user profile model in django as follows.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    job_title = models.CharField(...)
```

But, if I have created an organisation model, and will let multiple users belong to a certain organization, then how to modify the Django User model to that one organization has multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

create a new model that extends User model and then have a foreign key attribute named `organisation` in it

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to adjust the User model in any way. You have user profiles, each of which is tied to the respective user, so use your user profiles now:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
```

And then you can perform all lookups via Profile model. And if you need real user object, you can always get it as `profile.user`.

You can still [customize your user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) if you really want to of course.